# First things to first, does charges moves as the switch is opened of this parallel circuit?

Tags: voltage, switches, capacitance, charging, charge

[image]

\$  V_{0}:=\text{initial voltage of } C_{1} ~ \text{as the given diagram(which means )} ~C_{1} \text{has been charged}  \$

\$  \text{operationA := Close}\text{ switch1 and open switch2 and do charging against } C_{2}\$

\$  \text{operationB := Open } S_{1} \text{and close } S_{2} \text{ and disharge charges of } C_{2}  \$

We want to calculate the voltage of \$C_{1}\$ as above operation(opA and opB) are done \$n\$ times.

\$  Q_{1}:=\text{charge of } C_{1} \text{as first charged of } V_{0} \$

\$  V_{1}:=\text{common voltage as initially switch1 is closed.}  \$

\$  Q_{1}=\left( C_{1}+C_{2}   \right) V_{1}　=C_{1} V_{0}　  \$

\$  \therefore ~~ V_{1}　=\frac{  C_{1}    }{  C_{1} +C_{2}     } V_{0}　 \$

This voltage is equal to the voltage of \$C_{1}\$ as switch2 has been opened(obivous).

Currently below statements are confusing me.

\$  \therefore ~~ V_{2}　=\frac{  C_{1}    }{  C_{1} +C_{2}     } V_{1}　~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Why this can be said?}  \$

As one operation is done the voltage is multiplied by \$\frac{  C_{1}    }{  C_{1} +C_{2}     }\$

Hence as n operations are done ,the voltage of \$C_{1}\$ is

\$  V_{n}=\left( \frac{  C_{1}    }{  C_{1} +C_{2}     }  \right) ^{n} V_{0}\$

First things to first currently I can't get whether change of voltage of \$C_{1}\$ occurs as switch2 is closed and switch1 is opened.

I assume operationA is which makes the each voltage of capacitor same.

But what exactly happens as operationB is done?
[image]

What should I consider for next or what I've been missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what exactly happens as operationB is done?

When you perform operation B you are eliminating the charge on C2. The electrons on one side of the capacitor flow to the other side and combine with the positive charges there. The total net charge on cap is reduced to 0.

Assume C1 and C2 have the same capacitance and the system starts with Q charge on C1 and 0 charge on C2.

When you perform operation A the charge Q will be split evenly between C1 and C2.

When you then perform operation B the charge on C2 disappears leaving only Q/2 charge on C1.

If you repeat this sequence of operations again the charge on C1 will again be halved.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the **net charge** on a capacitor at dc is **always** zero.